# How to get youtube video title - vb

Tags: vb.net, youtube

I am currently creating a youtube downloader and I have the code to retrieve video thumbnails, however I want to find out a way to retrieve the video title and possibly the video size etc. If anyone can help please answer :D

Comment: please include some code so we can see what you have, what you have tried.

Comment: You're looking for the YouTube API.

Comment: Please Read [Here on the About Page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) about what StackOverflow is all about so that you know what we expect in a question.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Malachi should I provide the thumbnail code? because I haven't coded anything for the title yet, I don't know how to go about it.. I have tried some codes out of my head which are useless because they don't work..

Comment: you need to do some research on the Youtube.com API's and figure out what you want to do.  your Question is off-topic at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would concider you use [version 3 of the Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/). I don't suggest parsing the html of a youtube page, you never know when they will change the format and you'll be downloading too much information. The API is much more stable.

If you look at the [video section](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) .

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=BaW_jenozKc&part=snippet

(I can't test it on this computer)
By changing the part (or adding multiple part) you can get all the information you need about a video. Since the result is returned in json, you can use it with pretty much any programming language.

Also, read the Gettting Started. Youtube limits the number of query unless you register your application and get a developper key.

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the [.NET YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet), specifically the [YouTube API v2.0 – Retrieving Data for a Single Video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds#Understanding_Video_Entries) section.

You will need to query for a single video by the video's ID and then the pieces of data in the ATOM feed that comes back to you are:

- `feed/entry/Title` for the title of the video
- `feed/entry/media:group/yt:duration` for the length of the video

There does not appear to be a value returned for the size of the video, however.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. However couldn't I just navigate the web browser to the specified YouTube video and then try and receive the title by using getelemenid ..?

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try the youtube API:-
https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=BaW_jenozKc

It should return something along the lines of:-
"&title=youtube-dl+test+video+%22%27%2F%5C%C3%A4%E2%86%AD%F0%9D%95%90".

Credits to youtube-dl:-
https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py

Comment: The youtube API you refer to leads to a download. Shouldn't it be a link to the API docs instead?